# Python zscore calculation

Tags: python

I am in need of some help. I am completely new tp programming and I am trying to come up with a function that prints a zscore the greatest number, least number and the mean of the list. I can only get the number to print in an equation but not to be solved. I have to use raw python that calculate the score.

```py
population = [14, 28, 96, 97, 21, 29, 29, 4, 58, 
            42, 25, 97, 49, 33, 75, 53, 14, 53, 
            45, 87, 75, 66, 62, 55, 57, 44, 44, 
            94, 19, 96, 12, 59, 86, 88, 61, 68, 
            37, 64, 19, 46, 68, 98, 19, 54, 65, 
            30, 1, 82, 76, 3]

def mean(data_set):
    return sum(data_set)/len(data_set)

def stdev(data_set):

    variance = sum([(integer - mean(population)) ** 2 for integer in data_set])/len(data_set)
  
    return variance ** .5

def least(data_set):
    return min(data_set)

def greatest(data_set):
    return max(data_set)

def z_score(population):
    zscore1 = f'{greatest(population)} - {mean(population)} / {stdev(population)}'
    zscore2 = f'{least(population)} - {mean(population)} / {stdev(population)}'
    zscore3 = f'{mean(population)} - {mean(population)} / {stdev(population)}'
    return zscore1, zscore2, zscore3
print(z_score(population))
'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty much there. If you want to get the actual z scores instead of printing the equation, you could replace your z score function with

```
def z_score(population):
    zscore1 = (greatest(population) - mean(population)) / stdev(population)
    zscore2 = (least(population) - mean(population)) / stdev(population)
    zscore3 = (mean(population) - mean(population)) / stdev(population)
    return zscore1, zscore2, zscore3
print(z_score(population))
```